# Contents of GenericErrorPage.htm?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config

Could any post what the contents of GenericErrorPage.htm?

Comment: You have asked three almost duplicate questions about GenericErrorPage. Please close two of them out since they are all almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GenericErrorPage.htm is a generic error page that you need to create. See MSDN for examples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964622%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417(v=vs.100).aspx - There is an up-to-date link :)

Answer (score 1):

> The `<customErrors>` section enables
>   configuration 
>               of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
>               during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
>               it enables developers to configure html error pages 
>               to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

You can specify a page to which the redirect should occur on an error [specified in the **defaultRedirect** attribute].